# Table of contents and headers style

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

I have to write my paper in the same style as a book from my teacher. Most things are easy to do, but i have a hard time getting the table of contents and the headers right.

I tried to create a header with fancyhdr but i couldnt get the vertical lines at the end of the long horizontal one. Each odd page has the section in the header and each even page has the chapter. Odd pages also have a kind of tab on the right side, as seen in the first photo. How can in accomplish the same kind of style?

For the table of contents i tried something with tocloft, but i didnt realy see a option to change the table of contents style. So how do i get it like the second picture?

Any help would be much appreciated

[image: Header]
[image: Table of contents]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Did your teacher also use LaTeX? Ask him for the code. If not, please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting your issue. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Please always focus on one problem per question. So you should ask one question for the page header and footer aka page style and another one for the table of contents.

Comment: @Mensch He didnt write the book. It is just a book he thinks is nice, so our papers should look like it. At the moment i have like no working code because i dont even know where to start. The only code i have is a basic header, which looks nothing like the desired result.

Comment: @cabohah should i make two new questions, or should i change this one to one question and create a second question for the other problem?

Comment: He is asking you to write a `paper` in the style of a book? Normally a paper is published in a journal and one should follow the journal templates and guidelines. I see in the one image that it mentions something about a thesis! The toc has Chapters. So he either does not know what he is talking about or there is a serious misunderstanding somewhere.

Comment: @yannisl I'm not very familiar with all the terms, since this is my first research project. Because of that, i didnt really have an understanding of the different text structures. So when i handed in my 'paper', my teacher said it contained 3 kinda different things/problems, which should be split into multiple papers, or put them all in one 'book'. For the book each problem should have its own chapter. He gave me an example book to show what the final product should look like. Im sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @TimW OK thanks. My suggestion start with the memoir class for a book or scrbook, For articles I would use the standard article class. What field are you studying?

Comment: @TimW IMHO, as long as there aren't any answers, you can change this question. After getting an answer, you should be careful changing questions. The answer(s) should still be valid for the changed question.

Comment: @Yannisl The research im doing is about skybrightness, lightpollution and clouddetection. So probably astronomy. Im still in highschool at the moment.